# Subtracting predictions from linear regression model & stochastic error

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, predictive-models, error

Understanding that a linear regression model includes stochastic error, can I eliminate error from my model's predictions by subtracting one prediction from the other?

Let's say we have a model of the form:

Y = β<sub>1</sub> + β<sub>2</sub>X + β<sub>3</sub>X + e<sub>i</sub>

If I use this model to predict Y using observed data, predict Y based on a counterfactual and then subtract my counterfactual prediction from my factual prediction am I eliminating or reducing my model's error?

Would this be equivalent to something like (10+2) - (5+2) where 10 & 5 represent predictions and 2 represents model error? Would there be benefit from doing this? TIA.

Comment: I lack confidence that I am interpreting your procedure as intended.  Could you perhaps supply an example of what you mean?